# Image of a graded linear map is graded

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, graded-rings, graded-modules

Let $A$ be a graded ring, $M,N$ graded $A$-modules and $u:M\rightarrow N$ a graded linear map of degree $\delta$. I want to show that $\text{Im}(u)$ is a graded submodule of $N$. It is sufficient to prove that $\text{Im}(u)$ is generated by homogeneous elements.

Let $y\in\text{Im}(u)$. Then there exists $x\in M$ such that $y=u(x)$. We can write $y$ and $x$ as a unique sum of their homogeneous components: $x=\sum_{\lambda\in\Delta}m_\lambda$ and $y=\sum_{\lambda\in\Delta}n_\lambda$. This implies that $y=u(x)=\sum_{\lambda\in\Delta}u(m_\lambda)$, where $u(m_\lambda)\in N_{\lambda+\delta}$, for all $\lambda\in\Delta$.

I'm not sure what to do at this point; how can I use the above data to find a generating system of $N$ whose elements are homogeneous?

**Notation:** Let $(A_\lambda)_\lambda$, $(M_\lambda)_\lambda$ and $(N_\lambda)_\lambda$ be the gradings of $A,M$ and $N$, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are basically done already.  Each $u(m_\lambda)$ is a homogeneous element of $\text{Im}(u)$, so you have written $y$ as a sum of homogeneous elements of $\text{Im}(u)$.  That is, $\text{Im}(u)$ is generated by its homogeneous elements.

(Note that you don't really need to *find* a generating set of homogeneous elements.  You can simply take the set of *all* homogeneous elements of $\text{Im}(u)$, and see whether this set generates all of $\text{Im}(u)$.)

Comment: May I bother you with a related question? Is it necessary to assume $\delta$ is cancellable in order to show that $\text{ker}(u)$ is graded? I think I have a prove that doesn't require this: Consider the homogeneous components of $u(m_\lambda)$ in $N$; these must all be $0$ since the sum of all $u(m_\lambda)$ is zero. This shows that $m_\lambda\in \text{ker}(u)\cap M_\lambda$ for all $\lambda$. Is this wrong?

Comment: If $\delta$ is not cancellable, some of the different $u(m_\lambda)$ may have the same degree.  So you cannot conclude they are each $0$ from the fact that their sum is $0$.